# Leverage Google's spidering infrastructure to build your own niche index?

Tags: search, indexing, web-crawler, discovery

Let's say I want to build a specialised catalog of information that organisations can provide about themselves. We agree a metadata standard, and they include this information on webites.

Is it possible to use Google's infrastructure somehow to solve the problem of discovering sites with that metadata, and regularly re-spidering to pick up any updates?

The way this kind of problem is often solved seems to involve "registering" the site with the central index, who then build infrastructure to regularly visit each registered site. But I wonder if it can be done smarter - and without the need to formally "register".

For example, presumably you could make part of the metadata standard a unique string, which you could then literally Google search for. Then you'd process the rest of the page. But is there a more streamlined, smarter, more formal way to do this?

Comment: There is no guarantee that Google will spider a site or return it in search results if it does spider, so this has some inherent hit-or-miss

Comment: Well it looks like google does have searching by metadata. You *could* use some hacks, like all sites make a special url available, e.g. http://somesite/has-required-metadata and then you search for inurl and modify the url to get to the site's base url.

Comment: But does Google expose an API for this purpose? You'd want to know what sites had changed since you last visited, etc.

Comment: It does not seem to be exposed by custom search engine, if that's what you mean